# Xarray mask region based on multiple conditions

Tags: where-clause, mask, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm looking at a global netcdf file. I want to set all land points that are within the 60-75 deg N band to zero but keep the ocean points in that band as nan. As a second step, I want to keep the values on the land points from 60-75 but set all other land points to zero. Ocean values are NaNs. I just don't get my xarray script to do that - here is what I tried

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ds = xr.open_dataset('ifle.nc')

ds['Shrub_total'] = ds['Shrub']

shrub_total = ds.Shrub_total

tundra = shrub_total.where((shrub_total!=np.nan)&(shrub_total.Lat>60)&
                           (shrub_total.Lat<75), 0)
shrub = shrub_total.where((shrub_total!=np.nan)&(shrub_total.Lat<60)&
                          (shrub_total.Lat>75), 0)

ds['Tundra'] = tundra
ds['Shrub'] = shrub

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=2,figsize=(12,3))

ds['Shrub_total'].isel(Time=0).plot(ax=axes[0])
ds['Tundra'].isel(Time=0).plot(ax=axes[1])
ds['Shrub'].isel(Time=0).plot(ax=axes[2])

plt.show()
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

The left panel is the original data, for the middle one at least I managed to keep the data I wanted - but instead of the two massive violet blocks I wanted to keep the map with all values outside the selected area set to zero. The right panel was intended to be the 'inverse' of the middle one but I completely failed there. It feels like this should be such an easy thing to do but I just can't figure it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be mostly an issue with the logical side, as well as the method used to deal with the NaNs.

The below seems to work for me:

```
tundra = shrub_total.where((np.isnan(shrub_total)==True)|
                          ((shrub_total.Lat>60)&(shrub_total.Lat<75)), 0)

shrub = shrub_total.where((np.isnan(shrub_total)==True)|
                        ((shrub_total.Lat<60)|(shrub_total.Lat>75)), 0)
```

- I changed the `shrub` logical to an OR statement (we want to mask either less than 60 or more than 75 - it's not possible for somewhere to be both!).
- We use np.isnan()==True rather than ()!=np.nan. I am unsure about why we can't treat this the way you did... This necessitated further changes to the logic.

Note, I do not use python so this may be very hacky, and I'm sure someone else will have a much more elegant and knowledgeable answer but it intrigued me so I attempted it :)